# understanding C2DM auth token

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I read almost everything I could find about C2DM but what I couldn't understand is the auth token which the server needs in order to send a message.
Do I need to pass the server the password of the user in order for him to get the token?
Or am I missing something?
I don't want to ask the user to enter their password (if it's needed than it's pretty easy to do a phising app).
If I do need to send a token is there a way to get it with the accountmanager api?

Thanks.

After some consideration, is it possible I got confused and the auth token is really my gmail account(the developer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at JumpNote example project: http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/
It has both the client and server side code you can rummage through.

As for the auth token, JumpNote project has helper shell script to get one: http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/source/browse/trunk/scripts/get_auth_token.sh

This script will ask you for your Google Account credentials, and will retrieve an auth token that you can use for, I don't know, some time.

Comment: I understand how to get. The problem is what to get. My (the developer and the one who signed in to the c2dm service) auth token or the user who installed the app?

Comment: For sending messages, you'll use token issued to your developer account. You don't need separate token for each user of your app. It's a probably a good idea to create dedicated Google Account just for this, because the sender account will also be mentioned in the app. For the JumpNote app, it appears in AllConfig.C2DM_SENDER: http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/source/browse/trunk/src.shared/com/example/jumpnote/allshared/AllConfig.java